# How to install Metasploit Framework in puppy linux?

Tags: software-installation, puppy-linux, metasploit

I want to install Metasploit Framework but I don't know how! How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rapid7/metasploit-omnibus/master/config/templates/metasploit-framework-wrappers/msfupdate.erb > msfinstall && \
     chmod 755 msfinstall && \
     ./msfinstall
```